# "Other locations": Can others see my computer and just see my file system?

Tags: security

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10

I noticed that when i click on "other locations" (listed last in file browser) - i noticed i can see a lot of other computers on the network.

Is it possible to just log in to my computer that way?

Comment: Are you able to log into those other computers that way?

Comment: Haven't tried. afraid to do that actually :0 @OrganicMarble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on services installed on nearby computers.

*Other locations* usually inlude Windows Shares (i.e. SMB/CIFS protocol), which does not provide remote command execution. It is not SSH or Telnet or Fish.

But some computers may have SSH-server enabled, you can connect to them with `sftp://username@hostname`. This type connection requires username and password  and/or keyfile.

So the shortest answer is *No*.

Comment: So they'll need the same to connect to my PC (i mean, a user to my computer.. and connect via ssh..)

Comment: Yes, right. They need to know SSH credentials.